# Legal Far Call x86 Real Mode

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Is it considered legal in assembly to preform a far call in the following way:

```
    call farCall           ;call an example function that jumps to memory

    farCall:
    jmp 0x1111:2222        ;example address in memory
```

program loaded at 0x1111:2222

```
    ;do some stuff
    ret                    ;return to where the call was made, NOT THE JUMP
                            TO THIS ADDRESS
```

Please note that this is in 16-bit Real Mode, not 32-bit Protected Mode (I know there is a question on that already)

Comment: You would then return into the wrong segment (ie 0x1111 instead of whatever you called from), but sure, go for it, the assembler won't stop you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not save the full far return address (only the offset, but not the CS segment) on the stack while calling, so the subroutine at 0x1111:2222 cannot return to the caller using `retf` and most likely plain, near `ret` as well.

Why not simply `call 0x1111:2222`?

You could also simulate the stack effects of the far call instruction using `push cs`+`call (near)` or `push cs`+`push offset`.